# Does the Create 2 have the roomba room mapping software?

Tags: irobot-create

My understanding is that the Roomba has a sophisticated room mapping capability. Does the create 2 include that capability and is it usable by the hobbyist?

Answer (score 1):

No, Create2 does not have room mapping capabilities.  The Create2 is based on the Roomba 600 series chassis.  Only the Roomba s series, i series, and 900 series robots have mapping capabilities.

Disclaimer: I am an iRobot employee, but the postings on this site are my own and don't necessarily represent iRobot's positions, strategies, or opinions.